# designated Initialization of a Node with a pointer (C++)

Tags: linked-list, initialization, heap-memory, c++20, designated-initializer

When creating a new node in a linked list, is it legal to use *designated initializers* to initialize the members of the node as mentioned below?
Is there any repercussion in doing so and what would be a better way to achieve the same result?
(lang : C++)

```cpp
Node *temp = new Node{.data = value, .next = NULL};
```

```cpp
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};
```

Comment: That looks like C++ to me. If so you should remove the C tag and add a C++ one.

Comment: Designated initializers is a C standard not a C++ standard.

Comment: `Node *temp = new Node{.data = value, .next = NULL};` is C++ but you tagged `C`, so there is a contradiction. Please clarify.

Comment: Yes I used the the new keyword here by mistake, I should have used malloc. sorry for the miscommunication

Comment: @SameerAhmed well, then [edit] the question. Don't explain what you should have done but do it.

Comment: I am confused because you say it is C++, question is now tagged as C++, but you accepted a C answer. What is it really?

Comment: @pqans Designated initialisers are a C++ standard (since C++20).

Comment: @SameerAhmed `I should have used malloc`, `lang : C++`: You shouldn't use `malloc` in C++. Nor should you use `NULL`.

Comment: @eerorika: Sorry, i see you're right. I wasn't aware of. Now i am.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 the code is technically in c++ since I used the new keyword, I just wanted to know about designated initializers. The answer I accepted seems to work (with a different method) so I am not too bothered about the specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use function as a constructor.

```
Node* newFunction(int data) { 
  Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  newNode->data=data;
  newNode->next=NULL;
  return newNode;
}
```

And after that, you can use in the main part like that;

```
Node* newNode = newFunction(5);
```

Comment: `malloc` cannot construct C++ objects. It merely allocates memory

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 when I write this solution, he asked for the C language.

Comment: I know but meanwhile tags have been changed and OP clarified that their code is C++. I just wanted to leave a comment, because in C++ this answer can be considered wrong, not your fault

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I did not realize the tags has been changed until you inform me. I guess when the tag change, we can not take any notification.